# Extract JSON arrays into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have `project.json` file, which contains data like this :

```
{"student_id": "ST0001", "project": [{"subject_id": "S003", "date_of_submission": "2021-05-23 20:03:05"}, {"subject_id": "S004", "date_of_submission": "2021-05-24 21:03:05"}, {"subject_id": "S005", "date_of_submission": "2021-05-30 05:09:30"}], "project_year": "Second"}
{"student_id": "ST0002", "project": [{"subject_id": "S003", "date_of_submission": "2021-06-02 15:05:05"}, {"subject_id": "S007", "date_of_submission": "2021-04-28 21:03:01"}], "project_year": "Second"}
{"student_id": "ST0002", "project": [{"subject_id": "S0018", "date_of_submission": "2020-06-03 08:15:21"}], "project_year": "First"}
```

I need to extract `project_subject_id` and `project_date_of_submission` into a separate column like :

| student_id | project_subject_id | project_date_of_submission | project_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST0001 | S003 | 23/05/2021 20:03 | Second |
| ST0001 | S004 | 24/05/2021 21:03 | Second |
| ST0001 | S005 | 30/05/2021 05:09 | Second |
| ST0002 | S003 | 02/06/2021 15:05 | Second |
| ST0002 | S007 | 28/04/2021 21:03 | Second |
| ST0002 | S0018 | 03/06/2020 08:15 | First |

Here's what I have tired :

```
import pandas as pd

df_pr = pd.read_json('project.json', lines=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_json('project.json', lines=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(df).explode('project')
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('project')))

df.set_index("student_id",inplace=True)

print(df)
"""
student_id project_year subject_id   date_of_submission
ST0001           Second       S003  2021-05-23 20:03:05
ST0001           Second       S004  2021-05-24 21:03:05
ST0001           Second       S005  2021-05-30 05:09:30
ST0002           Second       S003  2021-06-02 15:05:05
ST0002           Second       S007  2021-04-28 21:03:01
ST0002            First      S0018  2020-06-03 08:15:21
"""
# If you want project_year at last then you can do this:

df["project_year"]=df.pop("project_year")

# It will change the position of project_year from 2nd to last.
```

We can explode that project column and normalize json of project and join with main dataframe.

You can try this as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("project.json") as f:
    lines=f.readlines()

dd=pd.DataFrame()
for line in lines:
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(line))
    df=df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('project').values.tolist()))
    dd=dd.append(df)
print(dd)
"""
  student_id project_year subject_id   date_of_submission
0     ST0001       Second       S003  2021-05-23 20:03:05
1     ST0001       Second       S004  2021-05-24 21:03:05
2     ST0001       Second       S005  2021-05-30 05:09:30
0     ST0002       Second       S003  2021-06-02 15:05:05
1     ST0002       Second       S007  2021-04-28 21:03:01
0     ST0002        First      S0018  2020-06-03 08:15:21
"""
# If you need student_id as index then :

dd.set_index("student_id",inplace=True)
print(dd)
"""
student_id project_year subject_id   date_of_submission
ST0001           Second       S003  2021-05-23 20:03:05
ST0001           Second       S004  2021-05-24 21:03:05
ST0001           Second       S005  2021-05-30 05:09:30
ST0002           Second       S003  2021-06-02 15:05:05
ST0002           Second       S007  2021-04-28 21:03:01
ST0002            First      S0018  2020-06-03 08:15:21
"""
```

What we are doing is reading each line of `project.json` file and converting it into dataframe`(df)` and appending each dataframe in `dd`.

Comment: I haven't noticed your code/I forget we can read json like that and wrote below code but you can use above code. :)

Comment: The first answer results as,    
|            | project_year | subject_id | date_of_submission |
|------------|--------------|------------|--------------------|
| student_id |              |            |                    |
| ST0001     | Second       | S003       | 23/05/2021 20:03   |
| ST0001     | Second       | S003       | 23/05/2021 20:03   |
| ST0001     | Second       | S003       | 23/05/2021 20:03   |

Comment: Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: I am not getting the output as you have show on the first answer, instead the `student_id` is looped thrice
Please see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H4kvTifQXQm9xzdZpj0ibrTOHbFr7D9C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I found that is same as you asked in question, please provide what is your expected output. And I think that your screenshot is same as I gave example answer, what is in your question as well.

Comment: Thank you for getting back, I am working on multiple json files where I'll have to use glob module to append all of the files together. For this I find your first answer easy to follow, but your first answer does not provide the expected output. Please see the screenshot, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X073ugn0dq_4Knpop024eUi0cf2jAWhp/view?usp=sharing. Your second answer works as expected but I need it in the first answer format. I am really new to Python, your support will be really helpful.